# Pointers for Custom Sitecore Analytics

Tags: analytics, sitecore

I am trying to do some very basic analytics on an existing sitecore site. All i need to find is basic behavior (page views, time on page) about logged in user. For instance, I need to be able to see which pages a particular logged in user has viewed, and how long he/she stayed on that page.

I am using Sitecore 6.4, is this possible?
If so, what is the preferred way to go about doing this?

Comment: Sitecore analytics for 6.4 is part of OMS. Do you have OMS? That's your first gate.

Answer (score 1):

The way that Sitecore's analytics work isn't quite like you might imagine. It's really not designed to do reporting on specific users without some configuration on your part. Basically it means that you have to set up their username to be captured.. which is probably easiest to do by assigning a tag to their session.  From there, there are things like the session reports and then you can pull up all the sessions for that tag (username).  This is something that you will probably have to spend some time and some trial and error to do... but it is possible.. just not necessarily an out of the box report.